# Not found vale of function

Tags: scala

I'm new in Scala and I have a problem.
My code:

```
object testObject {

def last[A](xs:List[A]):A = 
if (xs == Nil) throw new Exception("empty") 
else (xs.reverse).head 

def main(args: Array[String]){
println("Hello, world!")
last(List(1,2,3,4))
}
}
```

And intepreter says:

```
<console>:8: error: not found: value last
            last(List(1,2,3,4))
            ^
```

I clicked "Run selection in scala interpreter" in Eclipse

Comment: As a side note, ``last`` function exists on ``List`` already. So your implementation could well be ``xs.last``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

```
 Welcome to Scala version 2.10.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
 Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
 Type :help for more information.

 scala> object testObject {
      | 
      | def last[A](xs:List[A]):A = 
      | if (xs == Nil) throw new Exception("empty") 
      | else (xs.reverse).head 
      | 
      | def main(args: Array[String]){
      | println("Hello, world!")
      | last(List(1,2,3,4))
      | }
      | }
 defined module testObject

 scala> testObject.main(new Array[String](0))
 Hello, world!
```

So it must have to do with how you run it. My guess: You clicked "Run Selection" and only had the line with the call to `last` selected. Try running the `testObject` type as the main program. (In IntelliJ IDEA, this would be right-clicking inside the editor and selecting "Run 'testObject'". Not sure how it works in Eclipse, but it can't be that different.)

Comment: Yes, i didnt run it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I had originally misread your question. If I just copy your code into a Scala REPL, everything seems to be working fine. Have you tried the same?

Some general points though:

- You don't need `(x.reverse).head`, `x.reverse.head` works too.
- The argument to `main` is not used in the body, so can be omitted.
- Your call to `last` will return the last element of the list but then not use it.

Comment: Why last(List(1,2,3,4)) doesnt work? When we use function(parametres) and when we use parametres.function?